# How to use log4j more efficiently in selenium webdriver testing framework

Tags: logging, selenium-webdriver, log4j, webdriver, propertyconfigurator

I am working on a self learning project of selenium webdriver and using log4j for logging purpose.
There is a test class - contains all the test cases as methods
There is a page class - contains all the web elements and methods that can be used by test class

How should I work with log4j?
Test Class:

```
public class ConfiguringPropertiesFile {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String baseUrl;
    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ConfiguringPropertiesFile.class);

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "https://www.some-website.com/";

    // Maximize the browser's window
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@Test
public void test() {
    PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    SearchPage.navigateToFlightsTab(driver);
    log.info("Navigate to flights tab");
    SearchPage.fillOriginTextBox(driver, "New York");
    SearchPage.destinationTextBox(driver).sendKeys("Chicago");
    log.info("Enter destination city");
    SearchPage.departureDateTextBox(driver).sendKeys("12/25/2014");
    log.info("Enter departure date");
    SearchPage.returnDateTextBox(driver).sendKeys("12/31/2014");
    log.info("Enter return date");
}
```

}

Page Class:

```
public class SearchPage {
public static WebElement element = null;
static Logger log1 = Logger.getLogger(SearchPage.class);

/**
 * Returns the flight origin text box element
 * @param driver
 * @return
 */
public static WebElement originTextBox(WebDriver driver) {
    element = driver.findElement(By.id("flight-origin"));
    return element;
}

public static void fillOriginTextBox(WebDriver driver, String origin) {
    PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
    element = originTextBox(driver);
    element.sendKeys(origin);
    log1.info("Entering the source city as " + origin);
}

/**
 * Returns the flight destination text box element
 * @param driver
 * @return
 */
public static WebElement destinationTextBox(WebDriver driver) {
    element = driver.findElement(By.id("flight-destination"));
    return element;
}
```

}

In this situation, I am initializing log4j in both the classes and then the big issue is I have to call the PropertyConfigurator in each method.

How can I initialize it in better way and do not have to call PropertyConfigurator everytime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to have a single class, where you can initialize log4j and the invoke a method from that class to get the instance of log4j in each of the other classes.In the example below you can invoke the createLogger() method from any other class to get the instance of Log4j for example use:                       private Logger log = Logg.createLogger();

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;

public class Logg {

private static Logger _logger;
private static final String fileName = "defaultlog";
private static final String dateAndTimeFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy_hh.mm.ss";
private static final String logProperttFilePath = "./src/main/resources/com/framework/properties/log4j.properties";

static {
    /**
     * This is the static block which appends the log file name with the
     * timestamp to make it unique
     */
    try {
        String dateTime = DateAndTime
                .getFormattedCurrentDateAndTime(dateAndTimeFormat);
        String FileName = fileName + "-" + dateTime + ".log";
        File file = new File("logs/" + FileName);

        if (file.createNewFile()) {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.load(new FileInputStream(logProperttFilePath));
            props.setProperty("log4j.appender.File.File", "logs/"
                    + FileName);
            LogManager.resetConfiguration();
            PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
            System.out.println("Property log4j.appender.File.File = logs/"
                    + FileName);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.print("IO Exception in static method of Logger Class. "
                + ex.getMessage());
        System.exit(-1);
    }

}

/**
 * This method creates instance of the Logger class coming from log4j jar by
 * implementing a singelton
 * 
 * @return _logger - new instance if no instance exist else an existing
 *         instance if the method is invoked previously
 */
public static Logger createLogger() {
    if (_logger == null) {
        _logger = LogManager.getLogger(Logg.class);
        return _logger;
    } else
        return _logger;
}
}
```